# Shared java HashMap in a clustered environment

Tags: java, production-environment

I've a client application requesting some information from a url every 1 second.

In the server (a servlet & JSP application), in order to avoid DB access when it's not necessary, it's been implemented the next solution. Here's a snippet:

```
//a static HashMap where we save the last record inserted in db
public static Map<Long, Long> VALUES = new HashMap<Long, Long>(); 

// A lastRecordRead sent by the client 
if (VALUES.get(id) != lastRecordRead) {     
    //Access the database to get some information 
    //cause the last value read is different from the last record inserted
    ...
}else{
    //Do nothing
    //It's not necessary access DB cause the parameters match
}
```

This was working as expected in development environment.

The problem comes when we have a clustered environment. We have the server deployed in two nodes (using jboss), each one with its own HashMap, and its own values. So depending on the node we attack, we can 
get different values...

¿Is there any way to share this HashMap between the two nodes? I was looking for some answer where I don't need to keep the 2 maps updated, meaning not calls between nodes...

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm now playing with HazelCast, and it seems so easy that I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong...

In my server I'm using now HazelCast instead of the HasMap:

```
public static Map<Long, Long> VALUES = (Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(new Config())).getMap("VALUES");
```

When records are inserted:

```
        if (((VALUES.get(id) == null)||(VALUES.get(id) < lastIdInserted))) {
            VALUES.put(id, lastIdInserted);     
        }
```

When the server is called by the client app:

```
// A lastRecordRead sent by the client 
if (VALUES.get(id) != lastRecordRead) {     
    //Access the database to get some information 
    //cause the last value read is different from the last record inserted
    ...
}else{
    //Do nothing
    //It's not necessary access DB cause the parameters match
}
```

And I think, that's all. Could anyone confirm if this is ok or am I missing something..? Is this solution truly populating all over the nodes? I've been doing tests with 2 tomcats and it does work, but would it work with differents ips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **Distributed HashMap**. There are some frameworks out there. [hazelcast](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/manual/html/ch02.html) is one example. You can use Hazelcast community version (free).

You can also use Redisson (distributed computing) too: https://github.com/mrniko/redisson

Comment: I'm trying this approach. I'll let you know. Could you show me some snippet or article related, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should take a look at hazelcast document.

Comment: I'm currently doing it. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Use some distributed key-value like:
   http://memcached.org/

http://infinispan.org/about/

http://basho.com/riak/

http://hazelcast.org/

...and tons of others.

2. Use 'publisher-subscriber' concept and update each HashMap instance by events. This is typically implemented with some JMS broker:

   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19717-01/819-7759/aerbk/index.html
   https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html

The choice depends on your needs: for fastest read and seek, without networking delays but with slow updates - use second option. This is good solution for data that is not changing frequently: geographical names, addresses and so on.

As general case - use fist one.

Comment: I think I'm going to try memcached. If it works, I'll accept the answer as correct. A snippet would be appreciated, though... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this article http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078584/open-source-tools/use-memcached-for-java-enterprise-performance--part-2--database-driven-web-apps.html There is some code samples too.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm using jdbc instead of hibernate, but this could help anyway... As far as I know, after reading some articles on internet, it seems that in order to use memcached you need to install a server aplication and apart from the client... is this correct? In this case maybe, using other options as Halzelcast seems a better option to me...

Comment: Yes, but you asked about  distributed solution, not embedded, so will need some external server, doesn't matter will it be Memcached or Halzelcast or something else.

Comment: I'm not sure if I don't understand properly the solution, or I didn't explain well my case. 
The thing is that I just need the server to access this "shared" map in order to decide if I need to go to DB. In production enviroment, there's 2 nodes with the same app deployed (I guess it's the same physical machine, but it's not under my control) My client will ask one of the node server, and this should check the map for the last record inserted. If it differs from the last read from the client, it goes to the DB...

Comment: Couldn't I declare a static Map and use put and get functions...?
public static Map<Long, Long> VALUES = (Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(new Config())).getMap("VALUES");  
Didn't something like this work as I expected?

Comment: 'to access this "shared" map' that's the key.  Because we're talking about sharing something between two different servers - it can be done only via network connection. If you know that both nodes are on same server or even more - on same JVM instance then any distributed caching will not be needed.

Comment: 'Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(new Config())).getMap("VALUES")' No. This is embedded usage, without networking.

Comment: But as far as I know, if I've a static HashMap in my app, and this is replicated into 2 nodes, there will be 2 different maps, meaning each node has a different Hashmap with different values... Isn't it..?

Comment: Yes.  That's why I described second case in my answer.

Comment: Well, but my data is going to changue frequently, and you suggested first option to solve this kind of scenaries... Besides, it seems a more ellegant solution, as you don't need to bother keeping updated the map... Anyway, I'll keep working on the clues you gave me. I really appreciate them.

Comment: Hi there. I'm doing some test with with HazelCast (I've edited the question with my proposal), and all seems to work as expected... Why did you say, this won't work..?

Comment: Well, I don't know what exactly you are doing and what was expected, so cannot say is it wrong or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that going to the database is an overhead that you  can't afford? If you use the database then you can be sure that locking and concurrent access will be handled correctly. Using a HashMap means that you have to handle concurrent read and write access yourself, which could significantly add to your design, build and test effort.

Are you sure this isn't a premature optimization?

Comment: There gonna be a lot of client apps requesting for some info, so this is gonna be necessary. Besides, it's a customer requisite ;)